# How to reply to when an interviewer schedules you for a time you cannot make?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, hiring-process, email

I am doing a second round of interviews with a company I am trying to get a job with. I have been in contact by e-mail with the person scheduling the interviews and he wanted to do Wednesday at 1 and I replied I could do Monday but have an appointment from 1-1:30 and if another time Monday would work (I checked my sent folder and did say this). Now I've been CC'd on an e-mail to another person who will be attending the interview and it states the interview is scheduled at 1pm Wednesday, even though I explicitly said I can't make this time.

What should I do? Should I reply to everyone in the e-mail and say apologize for any confusion and say reiterate I am busy from 1-1:30 on Wednesday? Should I suggest another time?

Should I try changing my 1-1:30 appointment? I'm fairly certain it can be change from 2-2:30 but that probably wouldn't give enough time. The other appointment I have is for an interview with a different company.

Comment: If your interviews were scheduled a week in advance, the chances they can accommodate your original schedule are that much greater. If these interviews were arranged with just 48 hours' notice, then it's much more problematic to reschedule anything, although you could try.

Comment: @user16748 - Its really as simply as asking to schedule another time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, definitely reply to everyone involved and clearly state that you cannot make the appointment. You don't have to be specific about why you cannot make the appointment, unless they've specifically asked for a reason. Ensure that when you reply to all, you include everyone who's been involved in the process so far, so that no-one has an excuse to claim they were unaware.

Remain polite during your email, and clearly state that you're excited to interview with the company in question, but that you have prior arrangements that mean you cannot make that date. Make sure you give them full blocks of time (e.g. entire days) where you can definitely make the date, and then make sure that you give them exclusivity over those days. Simply telling a company 'no' isn't a great idea, unless you also suggest an alternative that could work for everybody involved. Also assure them that you'll make sure they get priority on any of the free days you've listed, and politely state that you've already told their representative that you cannot make the originally listed interview date.

Essentially, if the company you're interviewing with doesn't respect your life outside of work when you're not even working for them, then the chances are that they'll respect it even less when you are working for them. Of course, this is a tradeoff: if this is the only company you *really* want to work for, then it may be worth sacrificing other arrangements to meet with them.

Comment: Should I use the word misunderstanding/miscommunication/mistake or should I just focus on the fact I couldn't make that time?

Comment: @user16748 Just focus on the fact that you cannot make the appointment. You don't want to accidentally get into a blame-game here.